cant send a POST from postman to firebase firestore database
I'm attempting to send a POST request from Postman to a Firebase Firestore database using the following JSON body:
{
    "name": "John Doe",
    "email": "john@example.com",
    "phone": "1234567890",
    "password": "yourpassword"
}

However, I'm encountering an issue with my Node.js handler code. Here's the relevant part of my code:
const { 
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword, 
    getAuth, 
    signInWithEmailAndPassword, 
    signOut, 
    updateEmail, 
    updatePassword,
    sendPasswordResetEmail
} = require("firebase/auth");
  
const { 
    doc, 
    setDoc, 
    getDocs, 
    getDoc, 
    updateDoc, 
    serverTimestamp, 
    collection 
} = require('firebase/firestore');
  
const { 
    getDownloadURL, 
    ref, 
    uploadBytes 
} = require('firebase/storage');
  
const { db, auth } = require("../database/db-config.js");

const registration = async(req, res) =>{
    const {name, email, phone, password} = req.body;
    try{ 
        const accountCredentials = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
        const user = accountCredentials.user;
        const userDoc = doc(db, 'users', user.uid);
        await setDoc(userDoc, {
            name,
            email,
            phone,
            uid:user.uid,
            imgUrl : '',
            profilePicture : '',
        });
        res.status(200).json({success:true, msg:'Account successfully registered'});
    }catch(error){
        console.log('Sign up error:', error);
        if (error.code === 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
            res.status(400).json({success:false, msg:'Email is already in use'});
        }
    }
}

module.exports = {
    registration
};

However, I'm getting the following error message:
[FirebaseError: Function setDoc() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field name in document users/eTrWurjJaVZPYN4FC6dtWq1XXqO2)] {
  code: 'invalid-argument',
  customData: undefined,
  toString: [Function (anonymous)]
}

Interestingly, the POST request is successful if I predefine the setDoc method with hardcoded values like this:
await setDoc(userDoc, {
    name: 'test',
    email: 'test',
    phone: 'test',
    uid:user.uid,
    imgUrl : '',
    profilePicture : '',
});

But it fails if the data inside it is not predefined. How can I resolve this issue?

The error message is telling you that you provided a value of undefined to the document field name using setDoc.  You're going to have to do some more debugging about why that is - it's not at all clear from what you provided so far.  We can't see how you actually invoke the function "registration" and provide the values it requires as input.  Please edit the question when you have enough information that anyone can use to reproduce the problem.

Actually i have already solved it a couple minutes ago. I forgot to change the raw data type to JSON in postman. That is why I got that setDoc error. Thanks for your answer though, Doug!

That wasn't an answer, that was a comment.  If you have an answer to your own question, you can post it here (as an actual answer, not a comment) so others can learn from you.

I have already fixed the error. Turns out I forgot to set the raw body type to JSON in postman. That is why the setDoc() doesnt recognize the req.body previously.

When you are doing a Q/A session please provide more information regardinf the question and the answer. This is due to in case of others come to search the application process it would be nice to have that info in the head
